# Formula to Find the Exponent

Tags: exponentiation

Is there a formula that determinants the exponent used to get to an answer?

`n^x = y`

`x = ?`

`n` and `y` are known

ex: `2^x = 128` how do we get to `x = 7`?

Comment: Take the log of both sides to get $x \log n = \log y$, then divide both sides by $\log n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what logarithms are for:

- If we start with $ n^x = y $ (where $n$ is called the base you take to the exponent to)
- Then $ log_n(y) = x $ (the subscript $n$ is still called the base)
- Also, for calculators, you can input the base like this: $ log(y)/log(n) = x $